# image centered within 6 links in the header

Tags: html

I want to create a simple header with 4 links and an image. Total width should be 85%. Other 15% should be spilt between leading and trailing spacing.

1. Image should be 45%.
2. Each link should be 10%. should be vertically centered and word wrapped.

   ```
   |--7.5%--|Link1|Link2|---Image---|Link3|Link4|--7.5%--|
   ```

   Here is what i have so far. For some reason the links all group on one side and the image on another.

   **HTML**

   ```
   <body>
           <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
               <nav>
                   <a href="#home">HOME</a>
                   <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                   <a href="#contact">EXPERTISE</a>
                   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
                   <a href="#about">INDUSTRIES</a>
                   <a href="#about">FRIENDS OF MARY</a>
                   <a href="#about">CONTACT</a>
                   <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
               </nav>
           </div>

       </body>
   ```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.topnav nav{
    display:block;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    float:center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent, black,black, transparent); /* For Fx 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black, black, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

.topnav nav a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    width:10%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    word-wrap:true;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;;
}

.topnav nav img {
    color: white;
    width:45%;
    float: center;
}

.topnav nav a:hover {
    color: #008ed2;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

}
```

Can someone help fix this. Here is the [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3LLf31p2/) link.

Comment: to give you some direction, I suggest with nesting your `nav` elements inside of a `ul` element with each menu item having their own `li` - you can then adjust your `ul` and `li` elements to `display: inline` and position them how you like - Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/spnboxxc/

Comment: @MikeDiglio thanks for that. I was able to get the image aligned without using li/ul. They were giving me issues. Only thing remaining is to vertically center everything.Can you see the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/3LLf31p2/2/

Comment: on your `.topnav nav` CSS, you can make it `display: flex;` and add `align-items: center;`

Comment: @MikeDiglio had to add to `.top nav div` but that did the trick. thanks.